# Why is apache hadoop configuration module ignores CDATA?

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, escaping, cdata

I'm using `core-site.xml` file for hadoop operations, and load it with the `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` class.

It seems like regular escaped strings are being loaded correctly. However CDATA statements are coming out blank, and not parsed at all.

`core-site.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
          <name>cdata.example</name>
          <value><![CDATA[Joe's <&> Bar]]></value>
    </property>
    <property>
          <name>escaped.example</name>
          <value>Joe&#39;s &lt;&amp;&gt; Bar</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`Main.java`:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        File conffile = new File("core-site.xml");
        try {
            conf.addResource(conffile.toURI().toURL());
            System.out.println(conf.get("cdata.example"));
            System.out.println(conf.get("escaped.example"));
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("MalformedURLException");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

> null
>
> Joe's <&> Bar

Why is that? Is CDATA not proper escaping scheme according to the XML standard?

Comment: I suspect the code checks for `nodeName` equals `#text` and forgot to check for `#cdata-section` as well.  A very interesting experiment would be to change the XML to `<value>XXX <![CDATA[Joe's <&> Bar]]> YYY</value>`.  If you get `XXX  YYY` then it would be time to file a bug against Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop version up to 2.8.x parse CDATA correctly. In Hadoop 2.9 and above, the parser was switched away from the DOM based parser DocumentBuilder (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14501) in favor of a stax based parser FasterXML's woodstox (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14216 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14501) to improve xml parsing performance.

Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16749 which is targeted so that lines including versions 2.9.3, 3.1.4, 3.2.2, 3.3.0 and beyond will again parse CDATA correctly.